# What is the meaning of xor = (/=)?

Tags: haskell, xor, ghci

I found the code of logical gate xor written in Haskell, but I don't know what does this "`(/=)`" mean!

```
xor :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
xor = (/=)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**`(/=) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47--61-) is a function defined in the `Eq` typeclass. It tests if two items are different and returns `True` in that case. For `Bool`s, it thus checks if the first bool is different than the other bool, which is what a xor gate does:

| `x` | `y` | `x /= y` | `` x `xor` y `` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `False` | `False` | `False` | `False` |
| `False` | `True` | `True` | `True` |
| `True` | `False` | `True` | `True` |
| `True` | `True` | `False` | `False` |

Answer (score 7):

/= is the not equal operator. It is equivalent to xor for booleans, since xor is only true when the booleans have different values.